# Threads Beginner: What's the point in using a super() method within the sub class's(extending Thread class) constructor?

Tags: java, multithreading

A super() is used to execute super class's constructor from within sub class's constructor. In this program, the output remains the same with or without the super() inside the constructor. So could you please explain the difference  between having and not having super() in this scenario?

```
    class SomeThread extends Thread {
    String ThreadName;

    SomeThread(String ThreadName) {
        super(ThreadName); //Why Oh Why ?
        this.ThreadName = ThreadName;
    }

    public void run(){
        for(int ctr=1; ctr<=10; ctr++) {
            System.out.println("From "+ThreadName+"...."+ctr);
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in "+ThreadName);
            }
        }
    }

}

class ThreadAliveDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeThread FThread = new SomeThread("Some Child Thread");
        System.out.println("Some Child Thread is alive "+FThread.isAlive());

        FThread.start();

        System.out.println("Some Child Thread is running.."+FThread.isAlive());

        for(int ctr = 1; ctr<=5; ctr++) {
        System.out.println("From.."+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"..."+ctr);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        FThread.join();

        System.out.println("Some Child Thread is alive.."+FThread.isAlive());

        for(int ctr=6; ctr<=10; ctr++) {
        System.out.println("From.."+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"..."+ctr);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you extending thread in the first place? If I were you I'd just create a class implementing runnable and feed it to a new thread: `new Thread(Runnable r)` or just a method: `new Thread( () -> method() )`

Comment: But that's not my question :)

Comment: @Gelunox Nothing inherently wrong with extending `Thread`.

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 5):

Calling the superclass constructor `Thread(String name)` you explicitly set the *system* thread name which you can later get with `Thread.currentThread().getName()`. If you don't call the superclass constructor explicitly, a default constructor will be used which will assign the default thread name like `Thread-1`. Those thread names can appear in debugger UI, `jstack` output and so on, so it's a good idea to assign meaningful names to your threads. For example, when running your current code in Eclipse debugger you'll see:

[image: Thread name]

So you can see `Thread [Some Child Thread]`. But if you remove that super call, you'll see the following:

[image: No thread name]

Now it's just `Thread [Thread-0]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you *do* make the call to super as you have done, then you will end up calling the following constructor according to the JavaDoc:

> public Thread(String name)
>
> Allocates a new Thread object. This constructor has the same effect as **Thread (null, null, name)**.

So `super(ThreadName)` calls `super(null, null, ThreadName)`.

If you *remove* your call to `super(ThreadName)`, then the JVM will call the empty constructor `super()` automatically for you.  According to the JavaDoc you will end up making an *almost* identical call:

> Thread
>   public Thread()
>   Allocates a new Thread object.  This constructor has the same effect as
>
> **Thread (null, null, gname)**, where gname is a newly generated name. Automatically generated names are of the form "Thread-"+n, where n is an integer.

So `super()` calls `super(null, null, gname)`, where `gname` is an auto-generated name for the Thread.

The only difference in behavior between calling and not calling super() is the assignment of a Thread name.

Answer (score 1):

The `super(ThreadName);` statement invokes the `Thread(String name)` constructor of [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.String-) class. As the argument suggests, it sets the name of the `thread`.

While setting `thread`'s name may not be directly useful in this example, in general, `thread` name can be useful when debugging, since you can add thread names to your application's logs.